# CC Page Label not displaying properly

Tags: apex, visualforce, component, b2b, cloudcraze

I currently have a Visual Force component that should display several CC Page Label values. However only a couple of the page labels are showing, not all of them. They all have their respective existing record but I can't get them to appear for some reason. I'm declaring them like so:

```
<span class="bold_font">{{pageLabelMap 'headerText'}}</span>
```

I have cache indexing for CC Page Labels turned off, so it should be getting the updated value of `'headerText'` but it's not. Other spans declared the same way do work and are displaying properly.

Does anyone happen to know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being a mistake in the value provided in the storefront Field on the CC Page Label record